# About smack and facebook chat?

Tags: java, facebook, chat, smack

How to get from and to usernames using smack?
By using below code I can only get from user but n't to username.

```
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

         if ((message != null) && (message.getBody() != null)) 
              {
            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant());

          }
    }
```